# The cell contains with Units, date and time, How to arrive only the first date and time

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have Unit value, date, and time in a single Cell. I want to extract only the first Date and time as per the below-expected output in excel

current Output:

```
Colmn A                                         ColumB
0.43 L/L < 24/Aug/2020 11:16 25/Aug/2020 13:03
0.43 L/L < 24/Aug/2020 11:16 25/Aug/2020 13:04
0.43 L/L < 21/Sep/2020 09:51 22/Sep/2020 13:07
```

Expected Output:

```
Column A                                           Column B

0.43 L/L < 24/Aug/2020 11:16 25/Aug/2020 13:03     24/Aug/2020 11:16
0.43 L/L < 24/Aug/2020 11:16 25/Aug/2020 13:04     24/Aug/2020 11:16   
0.43 L/L < 21/Sep/2020 09:51 22/Sep/2020 13:07     21/Sep/2020 09:51
```

As I tried different formulas, I am not getting the desired results.

How I should arrive at the expected output

Comment: Can you show some formulas you have tried? Also, can you tell us more about the pattern of the string values. Would it always be the exact same length for example?

Comment: I have tried with =[@DateTime]-INT([@DateTime])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is **always** like that, you could do:

[image]

```
=VALUE(MID(A2;SEARCH("< ";A2)+2;17))
```

This will only work if:

1. Your data is always like the one you posted
2. Target date is always like `dd/mmm/yyyy hh:mm`
3. Your default regional settings are english (so words like `Aug` can be recognized as August. I forced in my image text to be `Ago` because my regional settings are spanish

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula in column B, it will extract the text from the middle of the cell but it need all the cells to be of same character length:

```
=MID(A1,12,17)
```

or you can type the first value in as it is appearing in column A and then on second cell press CTRL+E for Flash Fill.